# Optimize $x^2 + y^2 +2z^2 +z(x^2-y^2)$ subject to $x+y=2$

Tags: calculus, optimization

$$x^{2}+y^{2}+2z^{2}+zx^{2}-zy^{2}\overset{\left(x=2-y\right)}{\longrightarrow}4-4y+2y^{2}+2z^{2}+4z-4yz\rightarrow FOC: \; \begin{cases}
-4+4y-4z=0\\
4z+4-4y=0
\end{cases}\rightarrow y=1+z\rightarrow f\left(x,y,z\right)=2$$

at any point that satisfies

$$\begin{cases}
x=1-z\\
y=1+z
\end{cases}$$

Hessian $4\begin{pmatrix}1 & -1\\
-1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$ is positive semidefinite, so I cannot claim that these points are points of strict local minimum.

Question: how to show that these points are points of (not only local but) global minimum? As far as I understand I need to prove $f(x,y,z)\geq 2$, but I cannot imagine how to deal with inequality of 3 variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint : $4-4y+2y^{2}+2z^{2}+4z-4yz$ can be rewritten as $2(1+(z-y+1)^2)$

Comment: I don't get, what's the point of rewriting the derivative?

Comment: @Yaldc what do you mean ? Unless I missed something, your goal is to optimize $A(x,y,z)=x^{2}+y^{2}+2z^{2}+zx^{2}-zy^{2}$ subject to $x+y=2$. The OP correctly states that $A(2-y,y,z)=4-4y+2y^{2}+2z^{2}+4z-4yz$, and I, in turn, state that this last expression is equal to $2(1+(z-y+1)^2)$. Where did you see a derivative in my argument ?

Comment: Right, sorry, my mistake. $1+(z-y+1)^2 \geq 1 <=> (z-y+1)^2 \geq 0 $. Nice, thank you.

Comment: mathSE says that bounty may be awarded only after 23 hours, so only tomorrow.

Comment: By the way, this kind of degree 2 optimization problem (in any number of variables) is very straightforward, the procedure is simply to complete the squares and see what happens. It is a pity nobody here gave you a sufficient hint before, it would have avoided your wasting your rep putting a bounty on such an easy question.